# Re-play slow motion doesn't play anything

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, video, python-multithreading

The code below selects and plays in slow motion the last 8 seconds of a video.

**Problem:**
When the the button `clean` is pressed, it **resets the video path**, and allows for selecting a new video (path) by pressing `select` button again.

However, when the button `play slow motion` is pressed, it **doesn't play anything** after the new video is selected. What could be causing this?

```
 import tkinter as tk
 from tkinter import filedialog
 import cv2
 import threading
 from PIL import Image, ImageTk

 class VideoPlayerApp:
     def __init__(self, root):
         self.root = root
         self.root.title("Multimedia")
    
         self.root.geometry("900x542+200+1")

         self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="#2271b3")
         self.right_frame.place(relx=0.8333, rely=0, relwidth=0.1667, relheight=1)

         button_height = 0.15
         button_spacing = 0.08

         self.select_button = tk.Button(self.right_frame, text="Select video", command=self.select_video, height=2, width=15)
         self.select_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=button_height, anchor=tk.CENTER)

         self.play_button = tk.Button(self.right_frame, text="Play Slow Motion", command=self.play_slow, height=2, width=15)
         self.play_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=button_height + button_spacing, anchor=tk.CENTER)

         self.freeze_button = tk.Button(self.right_frame, text="Freeze", command=self.freeze_video, height=2, width=15)
         self.freeze_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=button_height + 2*button_spacing, anchor=tk.CENTER)

         self.clean_button = tk.Button(self.right_frame, text="Clean", command=self.clean_video, height=2, width=15)
         self.clean_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=button_height + 3*button_spacing, anchor=tk.CENTER)  # New clean button

         self.left_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
         self.left_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=0.8333, relheight=1)

         self.video_label = None  # Placeholder for video label
         self.paused = False
         self.video_path = None  # Initialize video path

    # Add white frames to right frame
    self.white_frame_top_right = tk.Frame(self.right_frame, bg="white")
        self.white_frame_top_right.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=0.05)

        self.white_frame_bottom_right = tk.Frame(self.right_frame, bg="white")
        self.white_frame_bottom_right.place(relx=0, rely=0.95, relwidth=1, relheight=0.05)

    def select_video(self):
        self.video_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Video files", "*.mp4 *.avi *.mov")])

    def play_slow(self):
        if self.video_path:
        threading.Thread(target=self.play_video_slow).start()

    def freeze_video(self):
        self.paused = not self.paused

    def clean_video(self):
        self.paused = True
        if self.video_label:
            self.video_label.destroy()  # Eliminate the current video label
            self.video_label = None  # Reset to None
            self.video_path = None  # Reset video path

    def play_video_slow(self):
        if self.video_path:
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_path)
            fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
            total_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

            duration = 8
            start_frame = total_frames - (duration * fps)
            if start_frame < 0:
                start_frame = 0

            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, start_frame)

            while True:
                if self.paused:
                    continue

                ret, frame = cap.read()
                if not ret:
                    break

                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                img_pil = Image.fromarray(frame)
                img_pil = img_pil.resize((self.left_frame.winfo_width(), self.left_frame.winfo_height()), Image.ANTIALIAS)

                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img_pil)

                if not self.video_label:  # If video label does not exist, create it
                self.video_label = tk.Label(self.left_frame, image=img)
                self.video_label.image = img  # Keep a reference to the image to prevent garbage collection
                self.video_label.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
                else:
                    self.video_label.configure(image=img)  # Update the existing video label
                    self.video_label.image = img  # Keep a reference to the image to prevent garbage collection

                if cv2.waitKey(3900 // fps) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break

           cap.release()
if __name__ == "__main__":   
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = VideoPlayerApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by _"It doesn't work"_? Function doesn't run or something? I cannot test Python code ... Did you try putting a **print** as the first line of function `play_video_slow`? Then also test another **print** as placed after that first IF, something like `print("current video path : " , self.video_path )` to be sure the function is running as expected. For example if function `clean_video` makes the var `self.video_path` become **none** then later it might affect `play_video_slow` (eg: no path is available).

Comment: Sorry, What i mean is when the buttom clean is pressed it´a supouse that when a NEW video is selected, if the button play slow motion is pressed again, it could  reproduce the new video as far as video frame had been cleaned but it doesn't, just the   first time.

Comment: _"Just the first time"_ does that mean you have to press multiple times before it works? Do you think it's possible there is some delay because a new file is being loaded/processed into the system? A test could be to (1) change to new video path (2) make/run a function to update paths with `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_path)` etc etc but then (3) use `play_video_slow` to play video using the While loop part onwards (the `while True:` that has `cap.read()` included)

Comment: No, it means that if video run eficiantaly and a user can select another video to same process can do it without need to close and reopen the app just with clean, select a new video and play in slow motion again...

Comment: Hi. I understand that your **expected goal** is to play a new video after a user pressed the "clean" (or path reset) button. **(1)** What we need to know is what you mean by _"It doesn't work"_? I suggested adding **print** at different points in your code to check that those functions are actually running. **Is there anyway for you to check Error logs**? (or make your own **print** loggings at important functions)... **(2)** Looking at `def play_slow(self):` try replacing `threading.Thread(target=self.play_video_slow).start()` with just this `self.play_video_slow`, now does the new vid play?

Comment: PS: I appreciate that maybe you want the `Threading` part to happen... but you need to test with as much basic setup as possible to find the problem.

Comment: what i meant with it doesn't work was precisely that once the Clean button is pressed; the second video selected and at press button play slow motion it doesn't play second video that was selected as the first time... Yes,  i made the printing suggestion to check that those functions are actually running. Now, trying to  adding/replacing the self.play_video_slow function either